# Pandas: `NaNs` when reading `.txt` file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a `.txt` file that I am attempting to read in pandas. When I open the `.txt` file, I see it has the content and data I expect. However, when I read the file in pandas, the data is missing and I only `NaNs`.

here's sample content from `.txt` file:

```
980145115   189699454           SD              Vacant Land Agricultural/Horticultural/Forest Vacant Land           3290522 216200  43.585481   -96.626588  10255   46099   I

707951172   189699522           AZ              Government, Special Purpose Religious           91630   26730           102-55-008  4013    I
```

[image: data-img]

I have tried different parameters of encoding and sep in `read_csv`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('s3://filepath', encoding='latin-1', sep="\t")
```

[image: nans]

Is there anything else I can try to read the data?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the file in question? Is it a valid CSV?

Comment: @esqew I have added a row from the file, how do I check if its valid CSV?

Comment: Trying to reproduce your error, I get a perfectly valid df from the sample data line you provided: `0  980145115  189699454 NaN NaN  SD  ...  43.585481 -96.626588  10255  46099  I` The numerical fields got read as numbers correctly, only the text fields got loaded as NaNs.

Comment: You probably need to specify the `dtype` parameter if you want the text columns to be read as such.

Comment: @joanis there are 6m rows in the file, so I am looking for a solution that can handle

Comment: Right, of course, that makes sense. I think the `dtype` parameter lets you specify a type for each column, and since you have 18 of those it ought to be feasible to do so. Can you add the header to your question, above the line you showed us?

Comment: Do you mean specify `dtype = object` ? There are no headers in the file.

Comment: I'm still testing and trying to find a working `dtype` value for your file, but not luck yet. Actually, passing `na_filter=False` instead seems to work: `0  980145115  189699454        SD           Vacant Land  Agricultural/Horticultural/Forest Vacant Land        3290522  216200  43.585481 -96.626588  10255  46099  I`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the separator you have choosen in [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Try to use whitespaces instead with `sep="\s\s+"` :

```
df = pd.read_csv('s3://filepath', encoding='latin-1', sep="\s\s+", engine="python", header=None)
```

Or with `delim_whitespace=True` :

```
df = pd.read_csv('s3://filepath', encoding='latin-1', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

Comment: The sample line OP added has whitespace inside one of the text fields, I think it really has to be parsed by looking for tabs, not whitespace in general.

Comment: @joanis I did try using `/t` as separator but it didn't work.

Comment: Right, you probably cut and pasted the sample data from the question as shown, but unfortunately for display purposes the tabs get converted to spaces. If you click on `Edit` under the question and copy-paste from the edit box instead, you'll be able to preserve OP's tab characters in the process. It's a bit of a gotcha, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

##### The short answer

I would change two things to your call to `read_csv`:

- pass the `header=None` argument,
- pass the `na_filter=False` argument.

```
df = pd.read_csv('s3://filepath', encoding='latin-1', sep="\t", header=None, na_filter=False)
```

#### Details

I copied your two sample data lines in a file called `file.tsv` on my computer.

##### No headers

You say your file does not contain a header, and by default `read_csv()` tries to interpret the first line as column headers. Just doing that, I get NaNs only for fields that were empty in your sample:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('file.tsv', encoding='latin-1', sep="\t", header=None)
          0          1   2   3   4   5   6   7                            8   ...  10  11       12      13         14         15          16     17  18
0  980145115  189699454 NaN NaN  SD NaN NaN NaN                  Vacant Land  ... NaN NaN  3290522  216200  43.585481 -96.626588       10255  46099   I
1  707951172  189699522 NaN NaN  AZ NaN NaN NaN  Government, Special Purpose  ... NaN NaN    91630   26730        NaN        NaN  102-55-008   4013   I
```

##### No NaN filter

The [manual for `pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) says that `na_filter=True` is the default, and that means logic is applied to detect missing values. If that's not useful for you, and you just want to keep empty fields as empty values in your DF, turn that off:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('file.tsv', encoding='latin-1', sep="\t", header=None, na_filter=False)
          0          1  2  3   4  5  6  7                            8   ... 10 11       12      13         14          15          16     17  18
0  980145115  189699454        SD                           Vacant Land  ...        3290522  216200  43.585481  -96.626588       10255  46099   I
1  707951172  189699522        AZ           Government, Special Purpose  ...          91630   26730                         102-55-008   4013   I
```

##### A lot of empty values

Now, notice that with no NaN filter, columns 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 are all empty, and several others too further down. If you look at the actual data carefully, you will see that you have several consecutive tab characters, which means actual empty values in your data. That's just fine, presumably those fields were optional in the original database, but they're behind a lot of the NaNs that show up when not using `na_filter=False`.

Comment: This makes sense, however, when I try your solution I get: `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3276802, saw 19
`

Comment: I would have to see the contents of that line to try to troubleshoot that one. That's halfway through your file!

Comment: I added `on_bad_lines='skip'`, so that should help.

Comment: so I tried you suggestion and it didn't throw an error, however, instead of `NaNs`, the content is simply empty / blank. `df = pd.read_csv('s3://filepath', sep="\t", encoding="latin-1", na_filter=False, header=None, on_bad_lines='skip')`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's expected, since you have a lot of empty fields in your file.

Comment: @kms I have a more fundamental question for you, though. This method loads the entire DF in memory. Do you need to do that for further global analysis with Pandas? If not, there are solutions that will let you process one line at a time instead, which would require a lot less memory in the end.

Comment: I need to run a set operations / functions that will need to be applied to all rows of data.

Comment: Ah, OK. Then I guess this approach is probably the right one for your application.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's an encoding issue.

In My case, I try to read My csv File using:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding="utf-16",header=0)
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).